# How to release built artifacts back-and-forth from one to another repo on GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I got a requirement to generate, archive and reuse the artifacts between two different repositories

**Repository A:**  Compile Angular code and create a `XLF file`

**Repository B:**  Use the `'XLF File'` generated above and create a `new XLF file`

**Repository A:**  Again use the `newly generated XLF file` to `create the final output file`

The activities mentioned above should be done using `gitlab-ci.yml`.  I am not sure how to handle this using GitLab CI.

We can `push` the artifact from `Repo A` to `Repo B`.   However, CI on `Repo A` should wait until `Repo B` pushes a new artifact to `Repo A` to complete the process

Comment: Your concern is with GitLab-CI. Why did you use tags [tag:git] and [tag:github]? Git*Hub* doesn't enter the picture anywhere; at least Git itself is slightly involved (though not enough to warrant the tag, I think). (Note: this isn't just a rhetorical question: I'm curious as to what causes this sort of wrong tagging, and whether there's some way to help avoid it.)

Comment: @torek git was the tag suggested by SO

Comment: Hm, that explains the [tag:git] tag, but not the [tag:github] tag...

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following approach and it worked fine or at least I was able to proceed

Due to some reason `'variables'` along with `CURL` did **not** work as expected but I did not analyze the root cause

**Repo A - Pipeline**

```
trigger-repob:                        (Trigger Project B of Repo B)                           
  stage: repob
  trigger:
    project: repob-namespace/projectb
    branch: devops 

test_job:
  image: $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/base-image:latest
  stage: test_pipeline
  when: delayed
  start_in: 2 minutes
  needs:                                (Use artifacts from Repo B/Project B)
    - 
      project: repob-namespace/projectb
      job: buildprojectb
      ref: devops
      artifacts: true
  script:
  - do something here
```

**Repo B Pipeline**

```
buildprojectb:
  image: php:7.4.11  
  stage: build
  script:
  - do something here
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - outputs/*.xlf
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would *not* push a generated artifact to another Git *source* repository.

But a GitLab pipeline can [retrieve an artifact produced by another one from its URL](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#access-the-latest-job-artifacts-by-url).

To avoid the back and forth, I would rather have 3 jobs instead of two

- the first generates `XLF file`
- the second curls/fetches that file, and use it to generate  `new XLF file`
- the third job curls/fetches that file, and complete the process.

Answer (score 0):

> How to release built artifacts back-and-forth from one to another repo on GitLab?

- Repository A:

  - Compile Angular code and create a XLF file
  - Send a hook to repository B that it just compiled

    - just `trigger:` https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#trigger , works like a charm. It's even nicely visible in the gui.
    - or API https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/
    - pass `variables: PARENT_PIPELINE_ID: $CI_PIPELINE_ID` to repository B so it can download artifacts from specific pipeline
- Repository B:

  - Use the 'XLF File' generated above

    - use `needs:` https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifact-downloads-to-child-pipelines to download artifacts
    - or API: have personal access token from repository A https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html added to environment variables and use API to download artifacts https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html .
  - create a new XLF file
  - use `trigger:` or API to trigger repository A

    - but this time trigger different `.gitlab-ci.yml` file like: `trigger: - project: repositoryA file: second_stage.gitlab-ci.yml` https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#trigger-child-pipeline-with-files-from-another-project
    - or use like `variables: SECOND_STAGE: "true"` and use a variable to differentiate
- Repository A:

  - run pipeline from the file `second_stage.gitlab-ci.yml`
  - download artifacts from repository B - `needs:` or API
  - use the newly generated XLF file to create the final output file

Overall, what you need is `rules:` and `needs:` documentation. On older gitlab, it was done with API.

> CI on Repo A should wait until Repo B pushes a new artifact to Repo A to complete the process

Don't wait. Let the API trigger it.

Comment: "Run pipeline from the file second_stage.gitlab-ci.yml".  Kindly let me know how can I trigger a specific job on another pipeline.  I am trying to find it but not successful.

Comment: Och, you can't trigger a specific job. You could: add `rules: - if $DISABLE_ONE_JOB when: never` to all jobs, except a single one with `rules: - if ! $DISABLE_ONE_JOB when: on_success` and then add `trigger: variables: DISABLE_ONE_JOB: "true"` for example. Or move this specific job to another `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and trigger that single one file. Och - you could set the job as manual, and then trigger it via API, that would work.

Comment: I tried with API call as follows but the job on another pipeline was not triggered.  curl --request POST --form token=${CI_JOB_TOKEN} --form ref=devops --form "variables[TRIGERRED_JOB]=test_job" "https://git.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/trigger/pipeline"'.   Am I doing anything wrong with CURL request?